# I want to write a plugin for Excel 2007 in JAVA

Tags: java, excel

I want to write a plugin for Excel 2007 in JAVA.

Is it possible?
Where can I get material to start it?

Comment: Are you serious? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I have seen people use excel as server applications and as grid applications.  Horrible, horrible solutions.

Comment: I have developed a "meta plugin" (that is to say, a middleware, which allow to use Java object in Excel functions): http://www.obba.info. Maybe that suits you. @Peter Lawrey: Excel as the core solution may be horrible, but it may serve well as a GUI to a library. I find it interesting as a GUI for testing a backend code (until the professional GUI has been created).

Answer (score 3):

Googling "java plugin for excel" returned this http://xll4j.sourceforge.net/ in about 0.18 seconds!

Comment: Looks like that add-in was never finished. There's a new Java Excel Add-In though called Jinx (https://exceljava.com) that can expose Java methods as user defined functions in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

In programming, I suppose the question should not be

***Can I do it?***

Instead it should be:

***Is there an existing tool that someone else made that I can use to do it?***'

If none exist, you can always make one! But in this case, it seams XLL4J may work for you.

Comment: Or the question could be: "is there a justification to make it THAT (unnatural and complicated) way ?"

Comment: They stopped the development of the tool and suggested XLLoop ([link](http://xlloop.sourceforge.net/)). It is very powerful if you use it in a professional/corp. environment.