# Does Excel 2007 supports plugins written in Java?

Tags: java, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want to write a plugin for Excel 2007 in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511435/i-want-to-write-a-plugin-for-excel-2007-in-java)

I want to extend some functionality of Excel 2007.

So I want to write my code in Java, will it be supported in Excel?

Comment: not only a dupe, dupe by the same user! tz tz tz

Comment: I havent got the answer thats why i have reframed it

Comment: The duplicate is closed. Actually I wonder why this one is closed. I was looking for a methodology to use Java for Excel Plugin Development too, until I created my own. http://www.obba.info is a Java plugin middleware for Excel. And there are a handfull of other products like XLLoop or XLL4J etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy as Java "applications" run inside a Java virtual machine and is ... a challenge to find a way to call class or instance methods from outside.

The [XLLoop](http://xlloop.sourceforge.net/) framework looks promising to me. That's at least one way to code and use java based functions.

Comment: There's a new way to do this that doesn't require running a separate process as XLLoop does - Jinx. Take a look at https://exceljava.com. It embeds the JVM in the Excel process and exposes your Java methods as Excel functions.