# Microsoft Excel Plugin Development in java

Tags: java, excel

I want to develop a Microsoft excel plugin in Java.
 Following url's i found for the guidance but not getting any approach :

http://xll4j.sourceforge.net/

[I want to write a plugin for Excel 2007 in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511435/i-want-to-write-a-plugin-for-excel-2007-in-java)

Please guide if someone is having a approach.

Thanks

Comment: I love Java but using Java as a plugin for a Microsoft application doesn't sound like the best choice.  How about C#?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this answer is probably too late for you, but just in case anyone else has the same question - I think this is what you need: https://exceljava.com

There are some basic examples included, and you can read about how to use it on the website (https://exceljava.com/docs/tutorials/first-project.html). There are tutorials for using it to create an Excel Add-In in Java, Scala and Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best approach for your question is this:

http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/

or

https://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Bro i really appreciate your help but if you can guide me to some precise point by which I can make excel plugin, The url you have given are suggesting to read, write and alter the excel spread sheet but my aim is to develop a plugin for Microsoft Excel.